# How to save the video using currentPlaybackRate in ios?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller, avfoundation

Reference link:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios

I'm selecting the video frames and store the video using the below delegate(didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo) method,

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    // 1 - Get media type
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    // 2 - Dismiss image picker
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    // Handle a movie capture
    if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge_retained CFStringRef)mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
        // 3 - Play the video
        MPMoviePlayerViewController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] 
            initWithContentURL:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]];
        [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:theMovie];
        // 4 - Register for the playback finished notification
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:)
            name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:theMovie];

 if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath)) {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath,self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know how the videos are trimming and stored in the mobile local.In the below path the file is storing. I'm getting those values in the NSDictionary media url.

```
Path ::: {
    UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.movie";
    UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL = "file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/3175A4BD-F24F-4745-B7AE-FBA4B9EBE90D/tmp//trim.zuyfI0.MOV";
    UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = "assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=740204CB-EE25-4A83-992A-F46115FC5B9F&ext=MOV";
}
```

Before storing the video i would like to change the currentPlaybackRate ? Can anybody provide some idea to implement ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do `theMovie.currentPlaybackRate = /* your value */;` if you just want to change the time scale during playback. If you want to actually save the video with a different time scale, then you'll have to dive into [AV Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html).

Comment: As you said i tried the code,                 MPMoviePlayerViewController* theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL: [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]]; theMovie.moviePlayer.currentPlaybackRate = 4.0;  But it's not working. Can you suggest any reference link to implement the same in AVFoundation ?

Comment: can you provide some more information on how to save the video with the different time scale using AVFoundation ? It would be really helpful for me. .

Comment: Do you want to just play the video faster or save the sped up video?

Comment: I have to the following
1. Loading any video from Video Gallery 2. Slow Down the video 3. Playing the slowed down video 4. Saving the slowed down video.      I have the similar question poster here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450864/how-to-use-scaletimerange-in-an-avmutablecomposition