# How to use scaleTimeRange in an AVMutableComposition?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, avfoundation

I have a question about scaling the length of video in an AVMutableComposition to speed it up or slow it down. I know the code to do it is

```
scaleTimeRange:(CMTimeRange)timeRange toDuration:(CMTime)duration
```

The problem is that I don't know how to use that code. What I have currently for my composition which has a video track that's been recorded and an audio track that's been supplied.

Can someone show me how to add this in to get my video track to be sped up or slowed down?

Here's my code :

```
AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audioURL options:nil];
AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:videoURL options:nil];    

AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionCommentaryTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio 
                                                                                    preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[compositionCommentaryTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) 
                                    ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] 
                                     atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo 
                                                                               preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) 
                               ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] 
                                atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition 
                                                                      presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];   

NSString* videoName = @\"export.mov\";

NSString *exportPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoName];
NSURL    *exportUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPath];
```

Comment: if any information is missing or not clear in the question please let me know. .

Comment: Did you solved it? :)